# UIDatePicker strange behavior in iOS7 inside UIPopoverController

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios7, uipopovercontroller, uidatepicker

Previously in my project, I was presenting a UIView containing a UIDatePicker object inside a pop-over controller to allow a user to make or modify a date selection. The code I use to present the control is as follows:

```
LocationPopVC *view = [[LocationPopVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationPopVC" bundle:nil];
view.delegate = self;
[view loadForDate];
pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:view];
pop.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 216);
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell.contentView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

Running on a device/simulator not using iOS7, I get this desired result:

[image]

Now, on iOS7, I know the UIDatePicker object was "flattened" and the colors were changed, as expected. However, when I present the object using the same code as above, the following occurs:

[image]

From this I bring some questions to the table:

1: Why is the control is being dimmed? Shouldn't it be white, not gray?

2: Why is the "highlighted" row way off center? Shouldn't it be on the center row? Regardless, isn't it supposed to just look like this?

[image]

I will stress here that 'no' code changes have been made, and the only difference being running on iOS7 vs iOS6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIPicker is now transparent. The gray color that you get is from the view under the picker. Try setting a white view behind it.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something silly...this did the trick! For anyone curious about the lines going across, I also had a UITableView behind my datepicker object which I forgot to set as hidden in the viewDidLoad initialization of the view.  Never was an issue before, since the old picker wasn't transparent.